# ¿Por qué en ajedrez podemos terminar en "tablas"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, expresiones, definiciones, juegos

***Tablas*** es otra forma de denominar un empate, pero solo se aplica en determinados juegos como las damas o el ajedrez. En el [DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Ysg8s8S):

> 29. f. pl. En el juego de damas o en el de ajedrez, estado en el cual ninguno de los jugadores puede ganar la partida.
> 30. f. pl. Empate entre competidores. Hacer tablas un asunto. Quedar tablas.

Normalmente se usa el término *empate*, especialmente en el ámbito deportivo. En el ajedrez (creo que para el juego de damas no hay competiciones de relevancia suficiente como para ver el término usado en los medios de comunicación) se usa sin embargo *tablas*.

Si observamos la entrada número 30 vemos que el uso de *tablas* para describir una situación de empate técnico se puede usar en otros ámbitos (como una discusión o una negociación) y seguramente este uso proviene del uso del término en el ajedrez.

¿Por qué en ajedrez usamos *tablas* para referirnos al empate? ¿De dónde viene el uso de "tablas" con esta acepción?

Comment: Voy a hacer una suposición que se me ocurre al ver la frase _quedar tablas_ aunque  me suena muy raro, yo pensaba que era _quedar en tablas_. Una tabla es plana y tal vez esa cualidad se haya utilizado para definir un empate, que es algo plano, llano, nivelado.

Comment: No sé si es muy convincente pero en [¿porque se dice tablas al empate?](http://www.ciudadajedrez.com/foros/ver_temaforo.php?idtema=47&autor=marciano) [sic] dicen _se llama tablas porq vien de la palabra tabula q significa tabla o sea tablas es entablar, disponer las fichas nuevamente en el tablero para una nueva partida, esta ha sido la explicacion +- convincente q he encontrado si alguien busca otra mejor bienvenida sea_

Comment: @fedorqui Eso de tabula me ha recordado a la expresion _tabula rasa_ que es algo así como "borrón y cuenta nueva", empezar de cero otra vez. ¿Tendrá algo que ver?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Según el *[Libro de los juegos](https://recreoanacronista.files.wordpress.com/2009/08/book-of-games-alfonso-x-1283.pdf)* (PDF, en inglés), publicado en Sevilla en 1283 y mandado escribir directamente por orden de Alfonso X, el primero en el que se ordenan y establecen las reglas del ajedrez y otros juegos en España, los juegos de "tablas" eran juegos pertenecientes a una misma familia (los juegos de tablero), como el backgammon (conocido en España como "tablas reales"). La palabra "tablas" hacía referencia en realidad a las fichas que se disponían sobre el tablero, más que al tablero en sí. Por ejemplo, habla acerca de un juego llamado "quinze tablas" en el que cada jugador dispone de quince fichas.

Por otro lado, hasta 1867 todas las partidas de ajedrez de los torneos oficiales que acabaran en "tablas" debían jugarse nuevamente. Según [la Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draw_(chess)), en un torneo en París disputado aquel año hubo tantas tablas que los organizadores tuvieron serios problemas para desarrollar el torneo, y se tuvieron que cambiar las reglas.

Si unimos esto a lo comentado anteriormente, la expresión parece provenir sencillamente de que para determinar el ganador de una partida finalizada en empate se debían disponer de nuevo las "tablas" (fichas) sobre el tablero. ¿Por qué solo se usa el término en el ajedrez? Bueno, en realidad en otros juegos "de tablas" se usa también el término. En el juego de las damas también se puede acabar una partida en tablas.

Comment: Buena jugada! He encontrado esto en español, no es el libro completo pero tiene bastantes referencias: http://www.ahepe.es/VICongreso/descargas/Jesus_Basulto.pdf. En una parte que habla del empate lo llaman _manera_ o _mannar_ (creo que sería mañar), no sé si después se empezo a usar lo de tablas por lo que dices de poner las tablas (fichas) en el tablero o porque quedan tablas en el juego y no se pueden mover ya.

Comment: @blonfu yo también he intentado buscar el texto original, pero no hubo manera. El más cercano es el que enlacé en inglés.

Comment: Como se puede ver en el *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* ([[1](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000779.jpg)] y [[2](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI20/00000780.jpg)]), la expresión "fare tavola" también se había usado en el contexto del ajedrez ("scacchi"), aunque su definición no corresponde exactamente a lo que hoy en día se llamaría "tablas" ("patta" en italiano), que es un concepto más amplio.

Comment: Este diccionario (que se propone documentar los primeros usos escritos de las palabras y expresiones) da un [ejemplo](https://books.google.es/books?id=2wt84IlQczgC&pg=PA484) de uso en el ajedrez en la *Tipocosmia* de Alessandro Citolini (1561) y otro ejemplo de uso figurado en el *Decameron* de Boccaccio. 
Por lo que he leído, el ajedrez se empezó a popularizar en Occidente a partir del libro que mencionas. Si esta expresión se usaba en Italia en el siglo XVI, me parecería plausible que también se usara "tablas" en castellano con un significado parecido.

Answer (score 5):

*Explicación larga:* No hay nada más que hacer, ¿volvemos a entablar las fichas sobre el tablero de ajedrez?

*Resumida:* ¿entablamos? ¿hacemos tablas? (para poder empezar otra vez y ver quien gana porque ya no es posible).

Mirando una de las definiciones de entablar:

> JUEGOS: Poner las piezas de un juego de tablero en el lugar que les corresponde para empezar a jugar.

Que guarda relación con otra:

> Empezar cualquier tipo de acción, actividad, negociación o conversación

Answer (score 0):

Cierto que las tablas definen un empate pero su esencia es un acuerdo. El ajedrez es un juego en el que prima la elegancia entre jugadores. El jaque mate sentencia a uno de los reyes pero tal sentencia nunca se ejecuta. Por ello, es recomendable entender el jaque como amenaza y el jaque mate como amenaza final o ultima amenaza, en lugar de como rey muerto, puesto que tal cosa en el juego no llega a suceder. Sobrevive el rey rendido como gesto de postramiento ante la superioridad rival, una especie de reverencia formal de uno de los jugadores ante el otro tumbando el rey vencido. Mi hipótesis es que tablas podría tener su origen en intercambio de documentos de acuerdo o quizás obsequios.

Answer (score 0):

No soy experto, pero quizá la expresión en latín Tabula Rasa pudiera tener algo que ver. Quedar en tablas es empatar, quedar sin resultado, juego nulo o dicho de otro  modo... empezar de cero (hacer tabla rasa). El parecido es evidente.